# Change from C:\ to D:\ to open local files and folders?

Tags: air

I could use some help with a problem I've been having:

I've started building a small app with Adobe AIR, using HTML and JScript (not Flex!). I need the app to be able to open folders that are located on another drive than C:. Till now, I just managed to open files or folders, but they are all on the same drive as File.applicationDirectory, File.userDirectory, etc.

How can I change the path to another drive than C:\? :-)

Thanks in advance for your time (and sorry for the mistakes, I'm from Germany and it's like 4.30 in the morning :D)

Daniel

**edit/concretion**

Basically, I just need to change the "air.File.desktopDirectory" line to another one that lets me open D:\ :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is solved!

```
function volume() {
     var test = new air.File("file:///d:/");
     test.openWithDefaultApplication();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this help?

```
private function getDrives():void
{
    var os:String = Capabilities.os.substr(0, 3).toLowerCase();
    var currentDrives:Array = (os == "mac") ? new File('/Volumes/').getDirectoryListing() : File.getRootDirectories();
    for each (var file:File in currentDrives)
    {
        trace("Drive: " + file.name + " Size: " + file.size);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer, but when I use that code, I get a parse error in the first line (private function ...).

Comment: Your answer seems to be ActionScript, apparantly the question asker wanted JavaScript code, this answer is more thorough though.